# Multiline "[redex]::match()" output displays as one line in powershell

Tags: regex, powershell, match

I'm using `[regex]::matches($string, $pattern)` to search lines in between two lines in a log file.
My file (excerpt):

```
-----end-----
AAA
BBB
CCC
-----start-----
```

My code:

```
$pattern = "-----end-----(.*?)-----start-----"
$string = Get-Content $input_file
$result = [regex]::matches($string, $pattern)
#Output one of the matches:
Write-Host ($result[0].Value + "`n")
```

Output:

```
AAABBBCCC
```

Expected output:

```
AAA
BBB
CCC
```

Somehow it looses line breaks along the line, which makes output (many lines in between matching pattern) barely readable. Any way to fix that?

Comment: How do you initialize the `$result`?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew sorry, missed that line in the code. Added

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may fix the issue by using

```
$pattern = "(?s)-----end-----(.*?)-----start-----"
$string = Get-Content $input_file -Raw
$result = [regex]::match($string, $pattern)
Write-Host ($result.Value + "`n")
```

Note:

- `(?s)` makes `.` match any characters including newlines
- `Get-Content $input_file -Raw` grabs all the file content as a single variable with line breaks
- `[regex]::match` fetches the first match found

Comment: Awesome. With Regex pattern change and adding -Raw option it outputs exactly what I need. Thanks!

Comment: @miguello Great, please consider accepting the answer.

Comment: Ok I found it now - it's a check mark below voting arrows. :) Couldn't find how to accept as answer, thought upvoting was enough. Sorry :)